# AWS EventBridge PutEvent Detail Malformed

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I have tried both AWS Go SDKs both versions and every time I get an error stating that the Details field is malformed.  The Details field accepts a JSON string.

In SDK V2 you basically have a struct for the event

```
type Event struct {
Details []struct {
    Key   string `json:"Key"`
    Value string `json:"Value"`
} `json:"Details"`
DetailType string `json:"DetailType"`
Source     string `json:"Source"`
```

}

The example then builds up the JSON string with this code

```
myDetails := "{ "
for _, d := range event.Details {
    myDetails = myDetails + "\"" + d.Key + "\": \"" + d.Value + "\","
}

myDetails = myDetails + " }"
```

And then make the api call

```
input := &cloudwatchevents.PutEventsInput{
    Entries: []types.PutEventsRequestEntry{
        {
            Detail:     &myDetails,
            DetailType: &event.DetailType,
            Resources: []string{
                *lambdaARN,
            },
            Source: &event.Source,
        },
    },
}
```

Basically I get an error saying that the string assigned to the Detail field is malformed. I believe this is because the example code generates a string with a trailing which is not valid .  However when you omit the , you get a nil memory reference.

[AWS SDK Example](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/code-examples/cloudwatch/putevent/)

The example for SDK version 1 also generates an error.
Any help would be great

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code on the page you linked is not 100% correct. They actually link the "complete example" at the bottom of the page, which has slightly different code:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/gov2/cloudwatch/PutEvent/PutEventv2.go#L108-L117

```golang
myDetails := "{ "
for i, d := range event.Details {
    if i == (len(event.Details) - 1) {
        myDetails = myDetails + "\"" + d.Key + "\": \"" + d.Value + "\""    
    } else {
        myDetails = myDetails + "\"" + d.Key + "\": \"" + d.Value + "\","
    }
}

myDetails = myDetails + " }"
```

But building the JSON like this is not ideal and error-prone, as you already found out.

I'd propose the following:

```golang
details := make(map[string]string, len(event.Details))
for _, d := range event.Details {
    details[d.Key] = d.Value
}

b, err := json.Marshal(details)
if err != nil {
    return
}

fmt.Println(string(b))
```

Checkout the playground to see it in action:

https://play.golang.com/p/E4ueZLGIKp4

Comment: Thanks Jens ... classic case on being fixated on the immediate rather than looking at the bigger picture.  Pretty poor though to have that difference

Comment: @Mark_T Yes, the state of the documentation is rather poor in some places. But I guess it is the matter of few engineers having to do a lot of things in that team. Glad that I could help.